# Page break just doesn't work for me in HTML

Tags: html, css

I need page break html feature for my project, so I just wanted to try few simple examples in order to learn how it works. Problem is, none of the examples I found online work, including 2 exampels I found on stackoverflow. These are examples I tried:
Example 1:

```
<html>
<body>
This is
<p style="page-break-before: always">
Page #2...
<p style="page-break-before: always">
Page #3...
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2:
[php code to break page after 6th row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685016/php-code-to-break-page-after-6th-row)

And W3schools doesn't provide example :(. I even tried in different browsers but nothing... Can someone please tell me what I am missing, or provide me with a simple few lines code that will actually break a page?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-break-in-html-printing This might help

Comment: there is no error, the page just won't break. Btw, I think I might be looking at wrong examples. I want my HTML page to break. It seems that all of these examples are for printer. I need something like
`
contentcontentcontent
contentcontentcontent
pervious page 1 2 3 4... next page
`

Comment: Try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before

Comment: Sorry, guys, my question is completely off. I need pagination, not page break. The reason for my mistake is probably because I used a wordpress theme that had shortcode pagebreak to paginate my content. I am really sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Instead of just a comment you should take a moment to also update the content of your post (& the title) to clarify your pagination issue